# Unity ResolveAll, and resolving unregistered types

Tags: c#, unity-container

*Simple question*; is it possible to `ResolveAll<T>`, for unregistered types?

In an ideal world, I'd have something similar to an `IPluggable` interface, which when resolved would return a collection of objects inheriting that interface.

```
// both unregistered types
public class PluginOne : IPluggable { }
public class PluginTwo : IPluggable { }

// returns instances of PluginOne and PluginTwo
IEnumerable<IPluggable> result = container.ResolveAll<IPluggable>
```

As far as I'm aware, it's achievable with alternatives such as StructureMap, but sadly our structure is built around Unity. The only solution I can think of is to create a bootstrapper to automatically register certain types using a bit of reflection and namespace mining?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I created my own extension that resolves types based on my interface IBlock. The extension only looks in the executing assembly but could potentially look anywhere you want. From this it should be possible to make an extension that does what you want.

IBlock:

```
using Microsoft.Practices.Unity;

public interface IBlock
{
    void Register(IUnityContainer unity);
}
```

Extension:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Reflection;
using Microsoft.Practices.Unity;

public class UnityBlockRegistrationExtender : UnityContainerExtension
{
    private readonly NameToTypesMap nameToTypesMap = new NameToTypesMap();

    protected override void Initialize()
    {
        var blockType = typeof(IBlock);
        var blockTypes = Assembly.GetEntryAssembly().GetTypes()
            .Where(block => blockType.IsAssignableFrom(block) && block.IsClass);
        foreach (var type in blockTypes)
        {
            if (this.nameToTypesMap.AddType(type.AssemblyQualifiedName, type))
            {
                var block = this.Container.Resolve(type) as IBlock;
                block.Register(this.Container);
            }
        }
    }

    private class NameToTypesMap
    {
        private readonly Dictionary<string, Type> map = new Dictionary<string, Type>();

        internal bool AddType(string name, Type type)
        {
            if (name == null)
            {
                throw new ArgumentNullException("name", "A name is required.");
            }

            if (type == null)
            {
                throw new ArgumentNullException("type", "A Type object is required.");
            }

            lock (this.map)
            {
                if (!this.map.ContainsKey(name))
                {
                    this.map[name] = type;
                    return true;
                }
            }

            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: With a bit of tweaking this lead me to the right answer. The key difference; I'm scanning all assemblies within the executing assemblies file path. Thanks @Wietze.

Answer (score 2):

Yes you are correct. Unity will not resolve any unregistered types (unless you ask for single instance of class not interface). And solution proposed - bootstrapper - is the one I use with success for many of my projects. The only problem I had was in selecting a list of dlls to scan which can be tricky if you want it to find extensions in your folder. The most save approach is to add a configuration section for this.

Answer (score 0):

There is an [extension for Unity](http://tecx.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=AdvancedConfigurationEngineForUnity&referringTitle=Home) that works very similar to Structure Map's config engine.

It allows you to scan assemblies for implementations of interfaces and gives you support for custom conventions as well.